# IF/Then VBA Code based on cell colour. Not value

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I'm sorry if this has been asked before. I have looked around and cannot seem to find the answer. I am new to VBA and would like some assistance.

Is it possible to to complete a IF/Then function on VBA based on colour, then replace the colour with a value.

Example:

If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 255 Then Cell.Value = 1

Some cells in the data table which are RED already have a value, others do not. I need to change them all to 1 so i can count them individually in a pivot table.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Possible but my guess is that you're working with coloring applied by conditional formatting, at which point you would need to work with `.DisplayFormat.Interior`.

Comment: I would argue that if the color is due to a conditional format that one should use the same rule as the conditional format and not the color of the cell in their logic.

Comment: Actually I agree with that @ScottCraner, good point.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
So, Originally the Macro stated (if older then X date = 255)  It also fills in all the blanks red. Which is correct.
I then copy this data and delete everything which isnt red. All the reds get replaced with a 1 so i can pivot.
I need to learn either how to add to it OR search (if Cell in range is RED then value 1)

Comment: Do While x < TotalRows
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then Cell.Value = 1
                                With Selection.Interior
                                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                                        .Color = 255
                                        .TintAndShade = 0
                                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                                       
                                End With

Comment: please [edit] the post to include any clarifications and not comments

Answer (score 1):

`Cell.Interior.ColorIndex` is typically a value from 1 to 56 (the size of the current color pallette) and represents the position of a given color in the pallette.

The `Cell.Interior.Color` property is a Long value representing an RGB color value. Here 255 would be red - same as the value of `vbRed`

So

```
If Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 255 Then Cell.Value = 1
```

should be

```
If Cell.Interior.Color = 255 Then Cell.Value = 1
```